# Count back percentage using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the code below where I'd like to the numbers count back to 0% once hover the object out. Also I can't figure our how to make the value disappear again as it was on load. Could you please help me solve this.

Thanks in advance.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
<div class="fill" data-width="80%"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
<div class="fill" data-width="50%"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: blue;
    margin: 10px auto;
}

.fill {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    background-color: red;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-align: left;
    z-index: 1;
    text-align: right;
}
```

JQuery

```
$(function() {
   $('.container').hover( function(){
      var width=$(this).find(".fill").data('width');
      $(this).find(".fill").animate({ width: width }, {
        duration:800,
        step: function(now, fx) {
                $(this).html(Math.round(now) + '%');     
        }
    });
   },
   function(){
      $(this).find(".fill").animate({ "width": "0px" }, 800);
    });
});
```

**jsFiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/zp8pe069/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/tajeja/1/edit?html,css,js,console,output)***

**CSS**: set `overflow: hidden` to `.fill` to prevent the text being visible after the animation ends.

**HTML**: remove `%` from the data attribute

**JS** and here you go. all you need:

```
$('.container').hover(function( e ){
  var $fill = $(this).find(".fill");
  var width = $fill.data('width');
  $fill.stop().animate({width: e.type=="mouseenter" ? width+"%" : "0%" }, {
    duration : 800,
    step : function(now) {
      $(this).html(Math.round(now) + '%') ;     
    }
  });
});
```

Note also the use of the `.stop()` method, if you hover multiple time hysterically :) it'll prevent endless animations.